# LocationManager not execute in android 8

Tags: android, location, android-location

this is my code for getting location :

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);


final double latitude = location.getLatitude();
final double longitude = location.getLongitude();
```

When I test and debug this on Android 4.4.2, it works well and it is debuggable but when it's run on Android 8 it seems code does not execute and is not debuggable

How can I get this to work on Android 8?

Comment: did you requested for runtime permissions  `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` or `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION`?

Comment: @JaydipKalkani yes sir , as i told it execute in android 4.4.2

Comment: Post android 8 error log

Comment: @erfan Runtime permissions are different from normal permissions, and they are not required below Android 6.0

Comment: Yes,i know it's working fine on android 4.4.2 but as starting from android 6.0 google has added runtime permission concept. so, i am confirming to you that did you requested runtime permission using 'requestPermissions()` method? If you don't then please refer [this](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try This**

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Location is needed...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, 1234);
            }
        }  else {
           //Permission is already granted. Get your location here

        }
    } else {
        //Do your stuff here for SDK below 23
    }

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case 1234:
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
               //Do your work
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Location is needed...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            break;
    }
}
```